# creating a tcp server and client

Tags: java, client-server, tcpserver

ive been trying to make a simple tcp server and and client. i'd like it to be a simple instant messenger. but i dont know which modules i will need to import in java to get them to run.

Answer (score 0):

Your client constructor doesn't connect to any server. 
Use this constructor instead:

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6789);
```